# Microsoft Botframework Prompts.choice not getting validation response

Tags: node.js, botframework

I am using `chatconnector` to connect my Bot to an frontend chat app and writing the bot's response to my own database. The problem is when I am validating a prompt the bot responds but there's no API for me to grab the validation response.

```
bot.dialog('/', [
function (session) {
    builder.Prompts.choice(session, "Which color?", "red|green|blue");

},
function (session, results, next) {
   //after the user respond, the bot validates the input, if it's not 
   //one of the choices, this next function in the waterfall doesn't
   //even run, therefore I have no way to write the bot response 
   //into my own chat database and render it for the user 

}])
```

Is there anyway I can grab the bot's response to the failed validation?

Comment: Did you ever resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: No.

Long answer: This is not currently a feature of the SDK.  If the input response to a choice prompt does not match any of the provided options, aka "intents", then the waterfall dialog does not proceed to step 2 because there is no match response. The system design is to warn the user and wait for them to input one of the provided choices either by name or number (depending on the channel). Eg. if the answer does not match any of the choice options, the framework will prompt the user with "I didn't understand. Please choose an option from the list." until a valid option is input.

Hacker answer: You would need to modify the SDK to suit your needs in this scenario, and then deploy you bot using your customized version of the SDK. The file you are looking for is [Microsoft/BotBuilder/Node/core/src/dialogs/PromptChoice.ts](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/blob/master/Node/core/src/dialogs/PromptChoice.ts)

Comment: Is there any way to get out of this validation loop, I am stuck because my prompt options did not render correctly and I am stuck in this loop now

Answer (score 0):

I have written a custom recognizer that allows Choice Prompts to be configured as optional. I.e. if a user does not click a button, but instead enters text that cannot be matched to a given choice, your waterfall dialog will proceed and you can handle the given user input individually.

Have a look at this:
https://gist.github.com/vwart/faddaee279aab5127707862ec4994574

The provided snippets are not compilable or runnable, I copied them together from my productive code. But it should be enough for you to apply the solution for your bot.

**How it works:**

**CustomChoiceOptions**:
When you start a Choice Prompt you pass a new bool flag called "optional" within the options.

**OptionalPromptRecognizer**:
A global recognizer registered at bot initialization. It is looking for messages in reply to a prompts that carries this optional flag. If it finds one, it will dispatch you a dummy dialog with a low score. The low score is important, so that other recognizers can beat it. E.g. LUIS Recognizer or the actual choice recognizer, which will return a score of 1.0 if the user actually hits a choice button.
If there is no recognizer that claims a reasonable score, our recognizer will be considered the best option and therefore our dummy dialog is triggered.

**optional-choice-dispatcher**:
The dummy dialog does nothing but creating a fake PromptChoiceResult with the index -1 and an entity that holds the actual user input. This result is then passed down your dialog stack, that means your next step can handle it.
This case can be identified due to the index of -1.

Have fun!